# how can i add user defined variable in pubspec.yaml for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

Basically I required to assign version and my local dependencies URL as user defined variable and assign the same in the path or wherever I wish to

Example like below

```
   mydependancyPath : D:\mylocalDependancy

   commonUtils:
   path:  mydependancyPath
```

> 1.Please let me know how can I achieve as like above
>
> 2.Is it possible to import another YAML file into pubspec.yaml

In Android I can achieve as below

```
dagger_version=2.8

"com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_version}"
```

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to import another YAML file into pubspec.yaml

- the answer to the above is No, it is not possible because `pubspec.yaml` does not support imports.
- Now for your main question :
  you can use [YAML Anchors and Aliases](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2019/05/reusing-data-with-yaml-anchors-aliases-and-merge-keys.html) for example  :

  ```
  # this line has the path , and stored in varName for future use we use *varName
  mydependancyPath : &varNam D:\mylocalDependancy
  # this line has the version number , so we can use *vers as a key that holds the value 2.8
  myversion : &vers 2.8
  #!join is to concatinate 
  path : !join [*varName, *vers]
  ```

[here is a more detailed resource](https://easybuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Writing_yeb_easyconfig_files.html#:%7E:text=yeb%20example%20easyconfig.-,Concatenating%20strings%20and%2For%20variables,join%20operator%20to%20support%20this.) because I'm not sure of the syntax but this should help with what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to update yaml variables, it's not possible to modify programmatically a YAML file.

But many people have faced the same issues and therefore according to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/3215) merged PR on the flutter project. You are now able to add a pubspec_overrides.yaml file to your project.

And simply overrides the variable you want :

```
dependency_overrides:
  my_package:
    git:
      url: <my_git_url>
```