# pubspec.yaml file cannot resolve path with '!join' keyword and anchors

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, pubspec

I'm trying to use an anchor in my pubspec.yaml file to facilitate entering dependency paths.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913922/8771168) answer, it seems pretty straight forward,
but Android Studio's inspection tells me that a dependency path specified as such cannot be resolved.

screenshot of the pubspec.yaml file:
[image]

and the resulting 'flutter pub get' output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?